# excel vba - remove certain type of text in article

Tags: string, vba, excel

Excel vba

I am trying to remove certain unwanted text ( from JSON ) from a article (basically different news article) through Excel VBA

- [{"body2":""},{"body2":"
- [{"body2":""}
- "}
- ,{"body2":"
- \n
- \t
- "}]

E.g of article that needs to be edited

**First example**

[{"body2":"AA Engages the Community Despite Training and Operations\n\n"},{"body2":"We thank Mr tin Tan for his suggestions in the forum letter titled \"Give time off for SDE to volunteer\", dated 25 Jan 2014."},{"body2":"hhh serves the critical need of our way of life. As such, training and operations is the main priority. Nevertheless, the AA is actively involved in supporting our community. Our units organise community engagement projects regularly, such as visiting homes to help and encourage fellow people, and engaging students through the Schools Partnership Programme. These projects allow our people to participate in community service whilst fulfilling theirservice commitments. In 2013, our soldiers supported more than 50 homes and engaged more than 30 schools.\n"},{"body2":"G.Huang\nHead\nJoint Manpower Department"},{"body2":"\nSDE's reply was published as \"AA Engages the Community Despite Training and Operations\", The NEWs Times, 28 Jan 14"}]

**Second example**

[{"body2":""},{"body2":"Local universities offer SDE options for early entry"},{"body2":"AA would like to respond to issues raised from letters to the News Times on enabling full-time staff  to enter universities earlier."},{"body2":"AA  is mindful that  Service requires staff to delay their personal pursuits, and will not make the duration of full-time service longer than necessary. The current two years of full-time  is necessary to train our staff to the required level of proficiency so that they can be part of the standing force to meet operational needs."},{"body2":"subsequently, completes his full-time service."},{"body2":"AA grants disruptions to stuffs to allow them to commence their university studies at the same time as This ensures that they are no better off or worse off than their peers in the same cohort, who have also served NS."},{"body2":"In terms of entry to local universities, there are more options now."},{"body2":"In addition, the University of Technology and Design has a unique academic calendar that starts in May, ahead of other universities, and its eight-semester course can be completed in 3.5 year."},{"body2":"Tm\nDirector Manpower\ndepert\n"},{"body2":" "},{"body2":"SDE was published as \"Local varsities offer staff options for early entry: AA\", The News Times, 12 Jun 12"},{"body2":""}]

**What i have done so far**

```
Public Function RemoveN(RemN As String) As String
Dim PosN As Integer
' remove any \n
PosN = InStr(1, RemN, "\n")
 Do While PosN > 0
 RemN = Replace(RemN, "\n", "")
 PosN = InStr(1, RemN, "\n")
 Loop
RemoveN = RemN
End Function
```

---

```
Public Function RemoveT(RemT As String) As String
Dim Post As Integer
' remove any \n
 Post = InStr(1, RemT, "\t")
Do While Post > 0
 RemT = Replace(RemT, "\t", "")
 Post = InStr(1, RemT, "\t")
 Loop
RemoveT = RemT

End Function
```

---

```
Public Function RemoveSlash(Rems As String) As String
Dim Poss As Integer
' remove any \n
Poss = InStr(1, Rems, "\")
Do While Poss > 0
Rems = Replace(Rems, "\", "")
 Poss = InStr(1, Rems, "\")
Loop
RemoveSlash = Rems

End Function
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want to do.  You mention XML but there's no XML there.  Your data looks like JSON.

Comment: hi tims,  just vba no xml , pardon me if i added it

Comment: So you've got it figured out with VBA?

Comment: not yet , i am only able to remove  \n and \t

Comment: and the random \

Comment: It would help your question if you would explain what's going on here.  Is the text you're cleaning up really a bulleted list with JSON and newline/tab sequences?  Where is it, and where is it coming from?

Comment: Hi tim , Yes ! my main objective here is to clean up and remove any thing related to JSON  from the mention bulleted list

There are one article to each excel cell and they are not from external sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This routine using regular expressions appears to clean up your article as you state.  In this example `body2` can be any word that does not include the colon.  But if you specifically want to look for `body2`, replace the `[^:]` section with `body2`

```
Option Explicit
Function CleanUp(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
    Const sPat As String = "\[?\{[^:]+:""|""}]?|\\n|\\""|,(?=\{)"
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPat

    'Replace pattern with a space
    CleanUp = WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Replace(S, " "))

    'cleanup spaces before commas
    .Pattern = "\s+,"
    CleanUp = .Replace(CleanUp, ",")
End With
End Function
```

### Explanation of Regex

```
\[?\{[^:]+:"|"}]?|\\n|\\"|,(?=\{)
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ don’t match at line breaks

- [Match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `\[?\{[^:]+:"`

  - [Match the character “[” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\[?`

    - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
  - [Match the character “{” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\{`
  - [Match any character that is NOT the colon character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `[^:]+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Match the character string “:"” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `:"`
- [Or match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `"}]?`

  - [Match the character string “"}” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `"}`
  - [Match the character “]” literally][4](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `]?`

    - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
- [Or match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `\\n`

  - [Match the backslash character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\\`
  - [Match the character “n” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `n`
- [Or match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `\\"`

  - [Match the backslash character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\\`
  - [Match the character “"” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `"`
- [Or match this alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `,(?=\{)`

  - [Match the character “,” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `,`
  - [Assert that the regex below can be matched starting at this position (positive lookahead)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=\{)`

    - [Match the character “{” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) `\{`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

[image]